# Enabling browser's form auto-filling

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I am making a signup form for my website.  It contains various standard form fields.  Such as: name, address, phone number, user name, password, etc.

When I double-click on a field (in Chrome 16), so I can auto-fill my address, I get this message:

> This webpage has disabled automatic filling for this form.

I didn't disable it, so how do I enable it?  I tried adding `autocomplete="on"` to the `<form>` tag, and to (some of) the `<input>` tags, and that didn't help.

Do I need to add `autocomplete="on"` to every field?  Also, how does the browser know what field is what?  Do I need to name the fields something special?

Another question: Is there some kind of `onautocomplete` event that gets triggered when a form is auto-filled?  On my form, when you enter a zip code, it looks in our database (via AJAX) and then gets the state and city (city and state are dropdowns, because zip codes can be for more than one city), and fills them in for you.  I was hoping I could have that run after the form was auto-filled.

P.S. I'm using the jQuery [form validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin, if that matters.

Comment: add autocomplete="on" to the <form> tag, that's it. Now erase your history for the last hour or so and refresh your page. Hopefully that might help. Regards

Comment: If you have one oracle account, login to the site, then click on Account next to your name, that page has autocomplete off, that you can see by watching its source code. Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali: Tried that, didn't help =(  I added `autocomplete="on"` to the `<form>`, opened the page in Chrome's Incognito mode, and when I tried to autocomplete the address field, I got the error in the question.

Comment: @GagandeepBali: "Oracle account"?  What are you talking about? "that page has autocomplete off, that you can see by watching its source code"  This is *my page*, and I'm trying to turn autocomplete *on*.

Comment: had you disabled your chromes autofill options, so check them too , by going to options, personal stuff, autofill. Hopefully (Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click) is checked.  Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali: I checked, Chrome's autofill is definitely on.  I just tested it by trying to signup for an account on another webpage.  It's something on my page that's disabling it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The problem was that the form tag didn't have `method="POST"` on it.

After Googling the message, I found a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58509), and one of the [comments](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58509#c4) mentioned `method="POST"`.

I added `method="POST"`, and voila!  Auto-fill works.

In some cases you may also need to add an `action` if the form doesn't have one. `action="javascript:void(0)"` works.

Note: Auto-fill seems to trigger the `onchange` event.

Note 2: As for how the browser knows what field is what, see this question: [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Comment: I have also added method=POST to my form, but the notice is still there...Chrome 21

Comment: @PeterO.: Did you give it an `action` attribute too?

Comment: @PeterO.: `<form method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)">` works for me.

Comment: I've forgot to put autocomplete="on" within the input element as well :)

Comment: @PeterO.: None of my inputs, nor my form have `autocomplete="on"`, but if that works for you, then great :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat complete madness, twitter bootstrap + jquery validation = no auto fill despite having action and method attribs on form tag and enabling form data save in firefox and chrome -- arggggghhhhhh! ;_)

Comment: actually seems to be related to ajax forms -- since the form never goes anywhere as far as the browser is concerned, then no form data is stored. Of course, that completely f-ing blows major, major chunks if this is in fact true

Comment: Yeesh what a horrid bug.

Comment: And it's still around, too.

Comment: @Chuck miraculously as of Chrome 36.0 form fill now works. Rocket's insight (`<form method="...">`) still holds, without that I suspect Chrome never did, nor will ever, work ;-)

Comment: Update: broken again, it's maddening, I give up, Chrome wins, back to CPU hungry Firefox (fingertips saved at least)

Answer (score 3):

The option to turn off autcomplete is normally located in the form tag, see the Developer page from Mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion). This should mean that normally removing that attribute should enable it again on a webpage.

Concerning the second part with the AJAX request, I don't think there's a listener for that, but you could add a function that checks the value of the field each x seconds for example, and if it changed you can perform your lookup.

Comment: I want to turn autocomplete *on*, not off.

Comment: I made it a bit more clear. Meant to say that if you can turn it off by adding that attribute, you should be able to enable it by removing the attribute.

Comment: Removing the `autocomplete` attribute (or setting `autocomplete="on"`) hasn't enabled it.  I still get the `This webpage has disabled automatic filling for this form.` message in Chrome.

Comment: Is this a .NET site (asking because of the message)? I think there's some JavaScript they use as a backup to prevent autocomplete happening.

Comment: @Tom: Nope, it's PHP.  And that message is from the browser (Chrome 16).