# How do I enable autofill in Chrome on a form inserted via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autofill

I'm getting the message "This website has disabled automatic filling for this form" - but I haven't. It's a form that is inserted via a handlebarsjs template. I have added a `method` attribute to the form, as well as `autocomplete="on"` on the `<form>` and all `<input>`s. It has a `<button type="submit">`.

I am at my wit's end with this one - any help would be awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling browser's form auto-filling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715000/enabling-browsers-form-auto-filling)

Comment: do you have an `action` attribute?

Comment: It does have an action attribute. I've tried it as empty, and tried adding a value to it as well. I have looked at that question, however the answers there don't fix my problem, and I think it has something to do with the fact that the form is generated and inserted via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO i found an answer. It turns out that, at least in Chrome 30.0.1599.101, a form has to be `method="POST"` to be allowed to autofill. So, it doesn't have anything to do with generated or not. Here's a bin, if you try to change the form `action` to `GET`, Chrome gives you a message about autofill being disabled. If you change it to `POST`, it works as expected.

http://jsbin.com/IyIkAhuL/1/edit?html,output