# Autocomplete text input

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I know there are a lot of JavaScript solutions, but is there an HTML5 method of having a text input with autocomplete? The datalist element is almost what I'm after, except it allows you to enter custom values rather than limiting you to what's in the list.

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery UI's autocomplete feature?

Comment: Im working with jQuery mobile on a mobile site. Ive heard they dont always play well together. I also wanted to avoid loading in an entire library just for this feature.

Comment: You can use `<select>` tag for this use case. In mobile, it gives the native UI right?

Comment: That would give me a select list however my list if far too long to scroll easily wich is why i want an autocomplete as you type.

Comment: Maybe add some JS code on submit to check whether the text is in the autocomplete array?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

HTML5 has an `autocomplete` attribute which can be specified as either `on` or `off` in a field.

Here's an example:

```
<form action="/form.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The way it works is that the values that you submit the first time will be suggested to you on subsequent times you visit this page on `keyup` of each field.

- The **key** issue in deciding to use this feature is one of browser compatibility. Your best bet is checking multiple browsers to make sure it works. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/forms) makes the support looks pretty bad, but I don't see any harm it using it to help those who have modern browers.

Other factoids about `autocomplete` from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp), don't hate in this case as it does cover the basics:

- When autocomplete is on, the browser automatically complete values
  based on values that the user has entered before.
- It is possible to
  have autocomplete "on" for the form, and "off" for specific input
  fields, or vice versa.
- The autocomplete attribute works with 
  and the following  types: text, search, url, tel, email,
  password, datepickers, range, and color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I need to prepopulate the options in the autocomplete.

Comment: I'm dont believe prepopulating is possible without using Javascript to at least show the options. What's wrong with a <select> tag? That is pre-populated and alphabetically  sortable on keyup.

Comment: Actually, `autocomplete` takes more than just `on` or `off`, it also takes `email`, `tel`, `given-name`, etc . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16864353/247696

Comment: I found that caniuse.com says the autocomplete attribute is supported in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete

Answer (score 80):

You should try the `datalist` element. It's clearly defined in [W3C HTML5 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element), probably the best option on the desk for now and near future.

> The datalist element is hooked up to an [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) element using the list
>   attribute on the input element.
>
> Each option element that is a descendant of the datalist element, that
>   is not disabled, and whose value is a string that isn't the empty
>   string, represents a suggestion. Each suggestion has a [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-value) and a
>   [label](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-option-label).

Google chrome and [chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) based browsers supports it since v21.x (As of Dec 2014, current version is 39, check compatibility status of [other browsers here](http://beta.caniuse.com/#search=datalist)) **Firefox** and **Opera** also supports for a long time. Modern(!) IE versions *partially supports* datalist.

**Demo:** A great [working datalist implementation](http://demo.agektmr.com/datalist/) by Eiji Kitamura.

**Polyfill** : Also check out the [RelevantDropdown](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RelevantDropdown/). It's a HTML5 datalist polyfill that depends on jQuery and Modernizr.

Try to run this example:

```html
<input type="search" list="languages" placeholder="Pick a programming language..">

<datalist id="languages">
  <option value="PHP" />
  <option value="C++" />
  <option value="Java" />
  <option value="Ruby" />
  <option value="Python" />
  <option value="Go" />
  <option value="Perl" />
  <option value="Erlang" />
</datalist>
```

W3 reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element

Answer (score 12):

This question is pretty old but I have an **updated answer for 2017**!

[Here's a link to the official ***current WHATWG HTML Standard*** for enabling autocomplete.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete)

***The following answer is from my original answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965106/1696153***

All you have to do now to trigger autocomplete is to name your `input` tag correctly.

Google wrote a [pretty nice guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values) for developing web applications that are friendly for mobile devices. They have a section on how to name the inputs on forms to easily use auto-fill. Eventhough it's written for mobile, this applies for both desktop and mobile!

## How to Enable AutoComplete on your HTML forms

Here are some key points on how to enable autocomplete:

- **Use a `<label>` for all your `<input>` fields**
- **Add a `autocomplete` attribute** to your `<input>` tags and fill it in using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values).
- **Name your `name` and `autocomplete` attributes correctly for all `<input>` tags**
- ***Example***:

  ```
  <label for="frmNameA">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="frmNameA"
  placeholder="Full name" required autocomplete="name">

  <label for="frmEmailA">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA"
  placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">

  <!-- note that "emailC" will not be autocompleted -->
  <label for="frmEmailC">Confirm Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="emailC" id="frmEmailC"
  placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">

  <label for="frmPhoneNumA">Phone</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="frmPhoneNumA"
  placeholder="+1-555-555-1212" required autocomplete="tel">
  ```

## How to name your `<input>` tags

In order to trigger autocomplete, make sure you correctly name the `name` and `autocomplete` attributes in your `<input>` tags. This will automatically allow for autocomplete on forms. Make sure also to have a `<label>`! This information can also be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values).

Here's how to name your inputs:

- *Name*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `name fname mname lname`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `name` (for full name)
    - `given-name` (for first name)
    - `additional-name` (for middle name)
    - `family-name` (for last name)
  - Example: `<input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="given-name">`
- *Email*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `email`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `email`
  - Example: `<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="email">`
- *Address*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `address city region province state zip zip2 postal country`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - For one address input:

      - `street-address`
    - For two address inputs:

      - `address-line1`
      - `address-line2`
    - `address-level1` (state or province)
    - `address-level2` (city)
    - `postal-code` (zip code)
    - `country`
- *Phone*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `phone mobile country-code area-code exchange suffix ext`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `tel`
- *Credit Card*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `ccname cardnumber cvc ccmonth ccyear exp-date card-type`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `cc-name`
    - `cc-number`
    - `cc-csc`
    - `cc-exp-month`
    - `cc-exp-year`
    - `cc-exp`
    - `cc-type`
- *Usernames*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `username`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `username`
- *Passwords*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `password`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `current-password` (for sign-in forms)
    - `new-password` (for sign-up and password-change forms)

## Resources

- [Current WHATWG HTML Standard for autocomplete.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete)
- ["Create Amazing Forms" from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values). Seems to be updated almost daily. Excellent read.
- ["Help Users Checkout Faster with Autofill" from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill) in 2015.

Answer (score 3):

With HTML5, a google suggest style autocomplete input is possible without any Javascript!

See this article:  [An HTML5-style "Google Suggest"](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-html5-style-google-suggest/)

However, it is not yet fully supported enough. The examples from the article will only work in Opera at the moment.

For now, it is probably best to just use a well-tested library with broad browser support like JQuery UI, which has an [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an input type="search" for this.  The user can choose from matches or just ignore the matches and enter custom text as they see fit.

Rather than hard code the options, I have used an array of strings and built the datalist with JavaScript.

```js
  let wordArray = ["aardvark", "bird", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "finch"];
  let str = "";
  for (word of wordArray) {
    str += "<option value=" + word + " />";
  }
  document.getElementById("myWords").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="search" list="myWords" placeholder="try typing words"/>
<datalist id="myWords"></datalist>
```