# How to make Chrome prompt to save credit card entries for autofill

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I'm implementing your average SSL secured payment form, and I've been able to get Chrome to consistently autofill stored credit card entries from a logged-in Google account. However, I haven't been able to find the magical series of bits and config to coerce it into prompting me to save new credit card entries.

Lets take a stripped down set of payment fields:

```
<form action="/someroute" method="post" id="pmntForm" autocomplete="on">
    <h2>Auto Fill Test</h2>

    <label for="nameoncard">Name on Card</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameoncard" name="nameoncard" autocomplete="cc-name">

    <label for="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="ccnumber" name="ccnumber" autocomplete="cc-number" />

    <label for="cc-exp-month">Expiration Month</label>
    <input type="number" id="cc-exp-month" name="cc-exp-month" autocomplete="cc-exp-month">

    <label for="cc-exp-year">Expiration Year</label>
    <input type="number" id="cc-exp-year" name="cc-exp-year" autocomplete="cc-exp-year">

    <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
    <input type="text" id="cvv" name="cvv" autocomplete="cc-csc">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This does exactly what I want for autofilling existing cards in my Chrome account:

[image: Auto Fill Test, it works!]

However if I enter a full set of new payment data; I expect that by the time the user clicks submit - Chrome should prompt to save the data as a new credit card entry (ironically this image is from a post of someone wanting to disable this):

[image: Prompt to save Credit Card]

Comment: Were you ever able to accomplish this?

Comment: Nope still waiting for someone to come by and save the day!

Comment: I have this exact same problem. So annoying.

Comment: did you get a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle in react, but it should answer your question.

### [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexcory/69z2wepo/50840/)

```
<form name="ccform" action="">
  <input name="cc-number" placeholder="Card Number" autocomplete="cc-number" />
  <input name="cc-csc" placeholder="Security Code (CVC)" autocomplete="cc-csc" />
  <input name="cc-exp-month" placeholder="MM" autocomplete="cc-exp-month" />
  <input name="cc-exp-year" placeholder="YYYY" autocomplete="cc-exp-year" />
</form>
```

Resources:

- [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome/9795126#9795126)
- [How does Chrome detect Credit Card fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168261/how-does-chrome-detect-credit-card-fields)
- [Chrome credit card autofill not being triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289477/chrome-credit-card-autofill-not-being-triggered?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [html5rocks: requestAutocomplete - take my money, not my time](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/requestautocomplete/)

You could also use the chrome dev tools to checkout other websites who have a working autocomplete form such as these:

- [Airbnb](https://airbnb.com)
- [creditcard.js](https://creditcardjs.com/)
- I'll add more when I find some

Not the perfect answer, but hope it helps! I will update when I find the completely correct solution. :)