# Auto complete for HTML forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autofill

I am looking for answers regarding auto complete for form fields.

How can I auto fill common inputs like First name, last name, address..?

In Chrome, If the user has a Google profile, fields can be autofilled.

It appears IE offers similar functionality:

(From MS Website)
"You can use AutoComplete to store passwords and other information that you type into web form fields. When you turn on AutoComplete, Internet Explorer will automatically fill in the fields you type into web forms frequently, like your name and address."

Is there any way I can ensure autofill happens, cross-browser, using HTML/JS?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question is pretty old but I have an **updated answer for 2017**!

**Now there *IS* a cross-browser standard on how to name your `<input>` tags in order to trigger autocomplete.**

[Here's a link to the official ***current WHATWG HTML Standard*** for enabling autocomplete.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete)

Google wrote a [pretty nice guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values) for developing web applications that are friendly for mobile devices. They have a section on how to name the inputs on forms to easily use auto-fill. Eventhough it's written for mobile, this applies for both desktop and mobile!

## How to Enable AutoComplete on your HTML forms

Here are some key points on how to enable autocomplete:

- **Use a `<label>` for all your `<input>` fields**
- **Add a `autocomplete` attribute** to your `<input>` tags and fill it in using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values).
- **Name your `name` and `autocomplete` attributes correctly for all `<input>` tags**
- ***Example***:

  ```
  <label for="frmNameA">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="frmNameA"
  placeholder="Full name" required autocomplete="name">

  <label for="frmEmailA">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA"
  placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">

  <!-- note that "emailC" will not be autocompleted -->
  <label for="frmEmailC">Confirm Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="emailC" id="frmEmailC"
  placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">

  <label for="frmPhoneNumA">Phone</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="frmPhoneNumA"
  placeholder="+1-555-555-1212" required autocomplete="tel">
  ```

## How to name your `<input>` tags

In order to trigger autocomplete, make sure you correctly name the `name` and `autocomplete` attributes in your `<input>` tags. This will automatically allow for autocomplete on forms. Make sure also to have a `<label>`! This information can also be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values).

Here's how to name your inputs:

- *Name*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `name fname mname lname`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `name` (for full name)
    - `given-name` (for first name)
    - `additional-name` (for middle name)
    - `family-name` (for last name)
  - Example: `<input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="given-name">`
- *Email*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `email`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `email`
  - Example: `<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="email">`
- *Address*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `address city region province state zip zip2 postal country`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - For one address input:

      - `street-address`
    - For two address inputs:

      - `address-line1`
      - `address-line2`
    - `address-level1` (state or province)
    - `address-level2` (city)
    - `postal-code` (zip code)
    - `country`
- *Phone*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `phone mobile country-code area-code exchange suffix ext`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `tel`
- *Credit Card*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `ccname cardnumber cvc ccmonth ccyear exp-date card-type`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `cc-name`
    - `cc-number`
    - `cc-csc`
    - `cc-exp-month`
    - `cc-exp-year`
    - `cc-exp`
    - `cc-type`
- *Usernames*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `username`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**: `username`
- *Passwords*

  - Use any of these for **`name`**: `password`
  - Use any of these for **`autocomplete`**:

    - `current-password` (for sign-in forms)
    - `new-password` (for sign-up and password-change forms)

## Resources

- [Current WHATWG HTML Standard for autocomplete.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete)
- ["Create Amazing Forms" from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#recommended_input_name_and_autocomplete_attribute_values). Seems to be updated almost daily. Excellent read.
- ["Help Users Checkout Faster with Autofill" from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill) in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

There is no cross browser way to do this, either the browser supports HTML5 and autofill, or it does'nt.

All you have to do to make it work, is use the correct names for the inputs, and the browser will handle the rest, and you have no access to whatever data the browser has stored.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" /> //first name
<input type="text" name="lname" /> //last name
<input type="text" name="email" /> //email
//etc...
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rttKS/)

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome), the regular expressions used by Chrome are as follows :

- **first name:** "first.*name|initials|fname|first$"
- **email:** "e.?mail"
- **address (line 1):** "address.*line|address1|addr1|street"
- **zipcode:** "zip|postal|post.*code|pcode|^1z$"

As long as your names can be matched by these regular expressions, the autofill feature will work in most browsers.

Comment: Where does HTML5 come into this, is this autofill only valid for HTML5?

Answer (score -1):

you can add autocomplete for form or each form fields. try this

```
<form autocomplete="on">
<input type="text" name="foo" />
....

</form>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry do you have a reference for this if possible? Is this an HTML5 attribute?

Comment: Yes, but it's only to turn the browsers autocomplete functionality on or off. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute "The off state indicates either that the control's input data is particularly sensitive (for example the activation code for a nuclear weapon)"