# why is chrome autofill not filling most fields

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a form that I cannot get chrome to auto fill. There are 3 inputs that are filling though..

Phone number, Email, and company name are all working as they should. I tried adding x-autofilltype to the other fields but nothing happens. Is there a better way than that?

Here is a portion of my code (note this is the html that comes from my php):

```
  <div class="checkout_holder">
<div class="contentText">
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="E-Mail" style="width:295px;"  title="E-Mail" />      
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone Number" style="width:295px;"  title="Phone Number" />      </div>      
        </div>
</div><!-- eof contact info -->

<div class="checkout_holder">
  <h2 class="checkout">Billing Address</h2>
  <div class="contentText">
             <div class="checkout_float_left">
                <select name="bill_country_id" style="width:301px;border:1px solid #bbb;">
                <option value="0">Please Select Your Country</option>
                <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
                etc.
                </select>       
            </div>

        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_firstname" value="First Name" style="width:140px;"    title="First Name" x-autocompletetype="given-name" />       
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_lastname" value="Last Name" style="width:140px;" title="Last Name" />     
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_company" style="width:295px;color:#bbb;" placeholder="Company" title="Company" />     
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_address" value="Street Address" style="width:295px;" title="Street Address" />        
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_address2" style="width:295px;color:#bbb;" placeholder="Apt, Suite, etc" title="Apt, Suite, etc" />        
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_city" value="City" style="width:295px;" title="Postcode" />       
        </div>
        <div class="checkout_float_left" id="states">
            <select name="bill_state" style="width:301px;border:1px solid #bbb;padding:2px 0;" id="bill_state">
            <option value="0" SELECTED>Please Select Your State</option>
            <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
        <div class="checkout_float_left">
            <input type="text" name="bill_postcode" value="Postcode" style="width:295px;" title="Postcode" />
        </div>

        </div><!-- eof contentText -->
</div>
```

Comment: Chrome autofill uses context clues to determine the form fields to fill. I'd bet the prefix on all your form names are messing that up. Try `lname`, `fname`, `address` instead of `bill_*`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Maybe this question is a duplicate of this one: [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)
 [by [Brent Washburne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/584846/brent-washburne)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly Chrome's autofill matches fields by type or by name much like we use contextual clues while reading. Try renaming your fields from bill_* to just *. i.e. bill_firstname -> firstname