# Autocomplete not working in any browser

Tags: html, css

thanks for taking a second.

I am working on a form on my checkout and I cant seem to get the browser auto fill to work on this form. It will show up on each field but when you select the option from the drop down it only fills the selected field and not the whole form.

I am not sure what code is causing this and my form code is very bulky, too bulky to post here. I will lead you to the checkout, hopefully someone can add a product and test the form for me. There has to be something thats not connecting these fields.

https://stretchshapes.net/dev/order.php?step=1

Thank you!

Comment: what browder have you tried ? cause here it work perfectly on chrome , it fills all fields

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are question is about auto filling form not auto complete

Please refer to for this feature which works with Google chrome:

[How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome/9795126#9795126)