# Login ID shows in wrong textbox after save password

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I have a login page with login ID & password, and we found if we choose "Save password for this page" in Google Chrome, after login into the main page, some other textbox was filled in the login ID automatically. What's wrong with the cookies?

The same problem happened in Firefox & IE

Comment: debug to find how the `other textbox` is populated.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh the problem is that, it's not easy to be reproduce, we cannot debug on this case

Comment: maybe this is caused by chrome autofill policy, see this SO answer to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome/9795126#9795126

Comment: @Zen I think it's not the auto fill problem, we've try to turn off the auto fill, it's still there

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the other textbox? (including any ASP.NET code such as bindings, runat=server etc). Are you using WebForms or MVC?