# Chrome does not autofill fields after adding a new input with type="checkbox"

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a login form for my website with fields for email address and password. This works fine, and all browsers I've tested correctly autofill the fields.

I've recently added a checkbox input to the form, and the Chrome browser (Version 50.0.2661.94) no longer autofills the password field. The autocomplete attributes on the inputs are set according to the [html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill-field). Chrome actually asks me if I want to save my password for the site, but still will not autofill.

As an experiment, I've tried changing the input type of the checkbox to "text" & other types, and autofill then works as expected. Safari & Firefox still autofill after adding the checkbox.

Unfortunately I can't seem to replicate this behavior in a jsfiddle, but hopefully someone can point out something I've missed. Here's a stripped down version of my form:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.3/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="ui form" method="post" action="login">
      <input name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email" class="email-input">
      <input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Password" class="password-input">
      <input name="sharedComputer" type="checkbox">
        <span>I'm using a shared computer</span><br/>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From this post it looks like this is nothing to do with `type="checkbox"`.
There are list of fields that chorme is trigger autofill.

But the credit here is to [@kmote link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Good suggestions. As I mentioned, If I change the input type to any different type, the form completely autofills correctly. So I still think it has something to do with type="checkbox". I don't need Chrome to autofill the checkbox anyway - just email and password. I've tried adding the autocomplete attribute to my fields (I'm using react-js, and x-autocompletetype is not supported), and this partially works. Now my email address is being autofilled, but the password is not.