# Chrome email field autocomplete options not showing for my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, email

As I visit many new websites for the first time, I see that:

1. For some websites, putting my cursor in the email field of signup form immediately shows me email options from what I had entered in other websites.
2. For other websites, putting my cursor in the email field does not give me any email options. And, I have to manually type every letter of the email.

I couldn't find what piece of code differentiates the two cases. For my website, I am stuck with #2. I am trying to achieve #1, where user can just re-use emails entered in other websites.

I used some code like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA" placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="email">
```

Comment: use `autocomplete="on"` https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: Share your html form code snippet and on which browser you are testing this

Comment: The `autocomplete` attribute isn't everything that you need to achieve automatically filling forms. You'll also need proper browser privacy settings. It does not matter that you provided an incorrect value to attribute - any value that is not equal to `off` by default will activate form autocompletion.

Comment: Also, you have to differentiate between email input fields in normal forms and forms where the input is combined with a password field (the email field is the username). In this case, the browsers use a completely different mechanism for autocompletion (namely the password manager instead of normal form autocompletion). Is this input in the same form as a password input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to enable `autocomplete`, but you have specified the wrong attribute.

**SYNTAX:**

> Autocomplete="on | off"

In order to save the email address entered for the *first time* though, you need to have a `form` tag with the attribute `method="POST"` on it. It is also recommended to use the `autocompletetype` attribute to help the browsers populate the forms more accurately.

NOTE: In some cases on older browsers you may also need to add an action if the form doesn't have one. `action="javascript:void(0)"` works.

**An example with autocomplete on and `method="POST"`:**

```html
<form method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA" placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="on" autocompletetype=”email”>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**An example without autocomplete and `method="POST"`:**

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA" placeholder="name@example.com" required autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

See also [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

The answers so far are wrong/outdated or incomplete.

Using `autocomplete="email"` is [perfectly valid](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill). But the browsers do not handle it very well at the moment. In Firefox and Chrome, only the `name` attribute is used for autocompletion. So you should stick with `name="email"`.

If the Chrome user really wants to have a proper autocompletion for every type that `autocomplete` supports, he/she has to fill out the [Autofill settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). After these settings are filled, the autocompletion does not depend on the `name` attribute anymore, but uses the type of `autocomplete`. I.E. it will suggest the user's email address for fields with `autocomplete="email"`.

So in order to have the best browser support, you should keep `<input name="email" autocomplete="email" [...]>`. As soon as there has been at least one submitted form with `name="email"` or prefilled Autofill settings, the browser should actually autocomplete your input field.

Further Resources:

- [caniuse: autocomplete attribute: on & off values](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff)
- [caniuse: input[autocomplete] (values besides on/off)](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1231)

> For some websites, putting my cursor in the email field of signup form immediately shows me email options from what I had entered in other websites.

I cannot reproduce that on the latest Chrome on Mac OS X. You actually have to *doubleclick* the input for the autocompletion to show up.

Comment: @SagarV I know, that is why i wrote "stick with" it. And I also explained how the autofill feature of Chrome works.

Answer (score 2):

Difference is in `autocomplete` attribute of `input` element.

**Syntax :** `<input autocomplete="">`

It allows the browser to automatically filled the input field based on the previously filled data.

Hence, In **`#1`** value of `autocomplete` attribute should be `on`.

**DEMO**

```html
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on">
```

In **`#2`** value of `autocomplete` attribute should be `off`.

**DEMO**

```html
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct values for the autocomplete attribute is **"on" or "off"** as you can see at : https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `autocomplete="on"` in `form tag`. like below.

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="frmEmailA" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```