# Save in browser password and username where username from <select> element

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

Simple login form

```
<form>
<select id="accessLevel" autofocus>
    <option value="1">View</option>
    <option value="2">Control</option>
    <option value="3">Service</option>
</select>
<input id="password" type="password" required>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Is there any way to store chosen text in  element as username in "save password" function of browsers on form submit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Comment: I think you will find that the `<select>` isn't really relevant to whether or not the form is autofilled. I think reading this answer would be quite helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9795126/1106901