# How can I let Firefox autofill username/password on the login page, but not other pages?

Tags: firefox, autofill

Right now, if I let Firefox 52 remember my password, it will also autofill it when I go to page I set up to create *new* users. Is there a way I can prevent this, perhaps by putting a different name or ID on either that page or the login page?

autocomplete="off" does not seem to work.

The site already works in Chrome (Chrome will remember my login info on the login page, but not on the "create new user" page.)

autocomplete="new-password" is also not supported in Firefox (see [bug 1119063](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119063)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

Comment: If you check those answers, you should be able to disable autofill in your page.

Comment: @Danziger This doesn't seem to help on Firefox. The site already works OK on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I decided to change the user creation process so a password doesn't need to be specified. Instead, the user enters a password after confirming their email address.