# html/thymeleaf - How to prevent input field detected as credit card related fields?

Tags: html, autocomplete, thymeleaf, credit-card, autofill

**Chrome detects some input fields as credit card fields. How do I avoid it in HTML?**

It seems that Chrome will detect such fields using some regex on field names etc (see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome/41965106#41965106)).

The only known solution for me right now is to rename the field.
I have tried using `autocomplete="off"` and `autocomplete="new-password"`.
Is there any HTML attributes or tricks that can avoid this?

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

**The Thymeleaf code for the input field:**

```
<td class="report-form-td2">
    <input class="calendar2 input-s" type="text" 
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" 
        th:field="*{dateStr}"
        maxlength="10" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>
```

**Which transforms to this HTML:**

```
<td class="report-form-td2">
    <input class="calendar2 input-s" type="text" 
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" 
        id="dateStr" name="dateStr"
        maxlength="10" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, This behavior is due to the use of `placeholder='dd-mm-yyyy'`. Google will detect it as a CC field.

**Temporary Workaround:**
Removing the placeholder.

**Extra Tips:**
Therefore, changing the input id/name attribute will not help in the case of this.
But if the field is using id/name like `mercId, mercName`, renaming them will help.