# Angular Google Chrome set Autofill

Tags: angularjs, angular, google-chrome

I have an angular application which has a input.

Now my problem is, that the value of the input doesn't get saved in the Google Chrome Autofill Variables.

Is there a way to save the input manually into the Browsers Autofill Variables?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can install

> angular-chrome-autofill-fix

module to solve this problem.
install this command:

> npm i angular-chrome-autofill-fix

also, you can use this link to read about this module:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-chrome-autofill-fix

The important note is, maybe this module doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a fix for another problem. My issue really is, that there is no form and because of this, google chrome probably has a problem with autofill there.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any specific way in angular to save the autofills in chrome.

here you can check [how form auto-fills works in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795126/1092672) by kmote. so that you can identify what needs to do to save input.

Highlight is that the browser looks at the field's name tag and makes an educated guess at what sort of data would go there (regex matching is a good naive way to do this). Chrome is working to get some sort of standardization so that this isn't quite as hit-or-miss.