# Remove history of input in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, history

I don't know how to remove input history in input how to do that?

i write value="" // not work

i read about autocomplete="off" and that's is not what I mean

```
<input class="barSearch" id="barSearch" placeholder="filtr" type="search" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
```

I have no idea what to ask google

This problem is only in chrome browser

Comment: Is this what you're talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill?

Comment: I believe this is browser controlled. Without actually seeing the way it works, I would think Chrome looks for the name / ids to look for previously entered values. You could randomise the input name and id on each page load or change it intermittently during a session. -- Not sure if this is even feasible - just an idea. Here's what got me thinking : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome/9795126#9795126

Comment: do u want to turn off the suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. If the entry is not removed, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[Source](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000553.htm)

Thanks to @Corey:

macOS: <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: macOS: Fn + Shift + Delete

Answer (score 2):

To remove autofill data in chrome. You will have to Clear your auto fill data.

1. Open the chrome menu using the three dots in the top, right side of your window and click settings, or navigate to [chrome://settings](http://chrome://settings) in your address bar.
2. Scroll to the bottom and go into the 'Advanced' section
3. Under 'Privacy and security' select 'Clear browsing data'
4. Then make sure only 'Auto-fill' form data is selected and press the Clear data button
5. Chrome has now removed your auto fill data.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.... generate aleatory id and data-attr with the real name of input field

```
 searchid=randomid
              <input class="form-control" type="search" style="width: 292px" name="<%=searchid %>" id="<%=searchid %>" data-name="PRLDEScripcion" value="" maxlength="100" placeholder="Teclee para buscar un artículo...">
                <script>  
                    
                    $("#<%=searchid %>").autocomplete({....
```

And change name on load

```
$(function () {
$("input[type='search']").each(function(){$(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("data-name"))})

}
```